# I want to make inset face planar

Tags: edit-mode

[image]

I make left geometry using inset faces(using 'depth' option) and after many tasks I want make inset face planar like right geometry(removing only 'depth' effect and moving only inner face).
Is there any tool for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Keyboard Period <kbd>.</kbd> > Set pivot to 'Active Element'
- Select center face, (the one to be moved,) Header 'Transform Orientations' dropdown > '+' create a new transform orientation from it
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> expand the selection to include the rim.
- Keyboard <kbd>1</kbd> go to Vertex mode
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>LMB</kbd> twice, Deselect and select one of the rim vertices to make it active
- <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

Comment: thank you for answer